# How to map and read an array of objects in an API response (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a "Quizz" React app using the (open trivia) API, I got the API and assigned it to my state and I'm able to read part of it but when I'm trying to read an array inside the object API I get an error, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to deal with this in the future.
This is my App component:

```js
function App(){
    const [quizz,setQuizz] = React.useState([])
    const [data,setData] = React.useState({
        quizzOn: true
    })
     React.useEffect(()=>{
         fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple").
        then(res => res.json()).
        then(apiData => {
            dataSetter(apiData)
        })},[])
     function dataSetter(obj){
         setQuizz(obj)
         
     }
     function toggle(){
         setData(prev => ({quizzOn:!prev.quizzOn}))
         };
         
    return(
        <div>
        {data.quizzOn && <StartFront onClick={toggle} arr={quizz ? quizz : []}/>}
        {!data.quizzOn &&<Quizz arr={quizz}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is my Quizz component in which I'm trying to read the data:

```js
function Quizz(props){
   const data = props.arr.results
   
   return(
        <div>
        <p>{data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "error"}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is working but anything I try after "results" give an error like:
`props.arr.results[0].question`

or:

```js
const data = props.arr.results.map(obj => {
  return <p>{obj.question}</p>})
```

Finally this the API I'm trying to read:

```json
{
  response_code: 0,
  results: [
    {
      category: "History",
      type: "multiple",
      difficulty: "medium",
      question: "The seed drill was invented by which British inventor?",
      correct_answer: "Jethro Tull",
      incorrect_answers: ["Charles Babbage", "Isaac Newton", "J.J Thomson"],
    },
    {
      category: "Entertainment: Music",
      type: "multiple",
      difficulty: "medium",
      question:
        "Who is the Pink Floyd song &quot;Shine On You Crazy Diamond&quot; written about?",
      correct_answer: "Syd Barrett",
      incorrect_answers: ["John Lennon", "David Gilmour", "Floyd"],
    },
    {
      category: "Entertainment: Television",
      type: "multiple",
      difficulty: "hard",
      question:
        "In &quot;Star Trek&quot;, what is the Klingon delicacy of &quot;gagh&quot; made from?",
      correct_answer: "Serpent worms",
      incorrect_answers: ["Earthworms", "Spaghetti noodles", "Klingworms"],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: You're passing an empty array as `arr` on the first render, but then setting it to an object with a `results` property after the useEffect runs, so on that first render `props.arr.results` (equivalent to `[].results`) is `undefined`and any further attempt access against it will throw an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am i getting and empty array when fetching an api with react hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601966/why-am-i-getting-and-empty-array-when-fetching-an-api-with-react-hooks)

Comment: i'm able to read and display `props.arr.results` but when i'm tring to do anything with the results array here when i'm getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time the component renders, the `Quizz` component is receiving an empty array, so is an error to do `arr.results` because arr is not an object

You should validate that you are receiving an object that have a key named `results`. Something like this:

```
function Quizz(props){
   const arr = {props};
   const data = props.arr.results
   
   if(!arr.results) return <></>;
   return(
        <div>
        <p>{data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "error"}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And rename the variable `arr` would be good too